# Piecewise linear $\sigma_i$ - notation question

Tags: rt.representation-theory, root-systems, cluster-algebras

In cluster algebra framework, in order to get root clusters, a modified version of a simple reflection is used. Define $\sigma_i:\Phi_{\geq -1} \to \Phi_{\geq -1}$ by setting:

$ \sigma_i(\alpha) =
  \begin{cases}
    s_i(\alpha)       & \quad \text{if } s_i(\alpha) \in \Phi_{\geq -1} \\
    \alpha, &\quad \text{else},
  \end{cases}
$

And they say that $\sigma_i$ is piecewise linear, as opposed to linearity of $s_i$. In what sense is $\sigma_i$ piecewise linear?

Comment: I guess $\Phi$ is the root system involved (for which there are a variety of notations in the literature), but in any caseyou need to be more explicit about the grading you have in mind as well as other notation used.

Comment: Isn’t it evidently piecewise-linear from the definition?

Comment: @JimHumphreys $\Phi$ is a crystallographic root system with a simple system $\Delta := \{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$ and $\Phi_{\geq -1} = \Phi^{+} \cup -\Delta$, that is $\Phi_{\geq -1}$ is a set of almost positive roots - union of positive roots with simple negative roots in $\Phi$ w.r.t. a fixed simple system $\Delta$. $s_i(\alpha)$ is the reflection of a root $\alpha$ in the hyperplane orthogonal to some simple root $\alpha_i \in \Delta$.

Comment: Ok, I guess a simple example of this piecewise linearity could be seen in the following example: let $\Phi$ be a root system of type $A_2$, with a simple system $\Delta = \{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$. We have that $\sigma_1(-\alpha_2)=-\alpha_2 \neq -\sigma_1(\alpha_2)$, so the linearity breaks for this case.